# crudCreate: how to redirect to specific page when success

Tags: javascript, reactjs, admin-on-rest

I'm using admin on rest for my project.

`this.props.crudCreate(resource, record, /specificPage, true);`

When the request is success, my page redirect to `/specificPage/undefined` path. In the document, I read this code -

`export const crudCreate = (resource, data, basePath, redirect = true)`

I'm really confused that it's not working correctly but `crudUpdate` 's working very well. So, my question is *How can I use crudCreate to redirect correct page?* In this case, it's `/specificPage` after success.

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any errors? if so, what are they?

Comment: after success, my page redirects to `/specificPage/undefined`. I think it should be only `/specificPage`

Comment: please upload the code that is doing the redirection.

Comment: It should just work like `crudUpdate`. Can you try to reproduce your problem with https://codesandbox.io/s/ElxGNxBY0 ?

Comment: Is your API returning the newly created object on success? If not then AOR will not know which ID to redirect to and your redirect will be to /page/undefined

Comment: brandNew I think my code is ok. just ask about crudCreate function...
Gildas Thanks, I will...
@kunalpareek
After creating a object, the response should return ID for this object and it will redirect to detail page?

Comment: Yeah. Your API is supposed to follow the Rest Contract. A POST request should respond with the object that was just created. Then on redirecting to the new page, it makes a GET_ONE kind of GET request to load the resource again. But during redirect it takes the ID from the ID in the response. Check if your API sends the object in the response.

Comment: @kunalpareek Thank you for your explanation. I got it. But Can I customize or do something to redirect to specific page what I want?

Comment: Hmm. Log the props on the show page. You will find a location prop. You can try and copy and modify it and see how it behaves. Plus you can try and see how the redirect prop calculates the new URL. See if that helps.

Otherwise @Gildas is more suited for such a discussion on AOR internals. These aren't trivial changes. You examine the root cause of the redirect to /undefined. It will happen mostly if you are using AOR in non standard ways or the API isn't following an expected contract.

Comment: Thank you for your helps. I appreciate that.